# Splitting up a boolean expression in Java

Tags: java, string, split, expression

How can I split a boolean expression in Java? For example, I want to get the following from the expression `a_1 & b_2 | (!c_3)`:

```
String tokens[] = {"a_1", "&", "b_2", "|", "(", "!", "c_3", ")"};
```

The names of the variables contain alphanumeric characters and underscores (`_`).

Comment: This is an XY problem. You think you need regexes, but you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
String str = "a & b | (!c)";
```

first, get rid of spaces:

```
String str2 = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

then, obtain the array you want like this:

```
String[] array = str2.split("");
```

**Update**: based on OP's changed question, another solution follows:

```
String str = "a_1 & b_2 | (!c_3)";  // initial string

StringCharacterIterator sci = new StringCharacterIterator(str);  // we use a string iterator for iterating over each character

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();  // this will be our array of strings in the end

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  // a string builder for efficiency

for(char c = sci.first(); c != sci.DONE; c = sci.next()) {
    if( c == ' ' ) {
        continue;  // we ignore empty spaces
    }


    else if( 
        c == '&' ||
        c == '(' ||
        c == ')' ||
        c == '|' ||
        c == '!') 
    {
        // if we stumble upon one of 'tokens', we first add any previous strings that are variables to our string array, then add the token and finally clean our StringBuilder

        if(sb.length() != 0) strings.add(sb.toString());
        strings.add(String.valueOf(c));
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    else {
        sb.append(c);  // we have a character that's part of a variable
    }

}



String[] finalArray = strings.toArray(new String[0]);  // we turn our list to an array

for (String string : finalArray) {
    System.out.println(string);  // prints out everything in our array
}
```

Comment: -1 This is a simplistic solution which only works when variable strings are one character.

Comment: @Erick: and OP didn't specify what you said as a requirement

Comment: Yes.  Because it wasn't specified to only work with one-character variable names, it should work with multi-character variable names also.  OP didn't place that restriction on its use.

Comment: @Erick: favor simplicity over common sense if possible

Comment: No.  That is a ridiculous statement.

Comment: @Erick: it does sound like it's ridiculous, but if you're thinking up of all possible cases in this particular problem that need to be solved, you would over engineer and overgeneralize the solution. If OP said that  '(' can be a part of a variable, then of course the solution would be different and much more complicated.

Comment: @darioo - with the last line you're close to the Strings internal `char[]`... and it will fail for multi-letter variable names. No downvote, just because you gave what the OP asked for... but I guess, it won't help.

Comment: @darioo: The OP has edited the question - and now your answer doesn't work.  This is because you failed to take into account multiple-character variable names.  This has nothing to do with `(` being part of a variable - this has to do with variables being multiple characters in length.  Look at the question again.

Comment: @Erick then that's the OP's fault for not saying what he wanted clearly.

Comment: @Philip: True, but that's who we're here to help.

Comment: @Erick yes. one way to help them is to answer their question and ask "is this what you wanted?". that gives them the opportunity to say "actually, no, what I wanted is more like..." Another approach is to ask them up front what they really want (particularly if you suspect an XY problem). But it's foolish to just guess what the OP really wants without stating your assumptions, because the consequences of guessing wrong are that you have confused yourself and the OP massively, and driven the discussion down a blind alley.

Comment: @Philip: In this case, I was dead on.  Success requires no alibi.

Comment: This algorithm won't work correctly if our statement contains only 1 word (like this statement: `a_1`). It will work if we add ```if (sb.length() > 0) tokens.add(sb.toString());``` after the first `for` loop and before defining `finalArray`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to parse the String - maybe to [create a syntax tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593814/syntax-tree-from-boolean-expression) and evaluate the expression -, then it's better to parse the String with a simple switch expression:

```
// for each char c in String
switch (c) {
  case '&': processAnd();break;
  case '|': processOr();break;
  case '!': processNot();break;
  case '(': processOpenPara();break;
  case ')': processClosePara();break;
  case ' ': break;
  default:  processVarName(); break;
}
```

This is just a stub to show the pattern. You may want to use a stack to evaluate the expression.